# How to use xor functionality in angular js expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The html is

```
<form name="businessFormAbout" ng-show="(businessFormAbout.$submitted)^(businessForm.$submitted)">
```

This is the 2nd form. By default this form will be hidden until the first form is submitted. Again it will show when the first form is submitted. After the second one(this form tag)is submitted again it will hide.

So `ng-show` will be true when [1^0 = 1], [0^0 = 0] and [1^1 = 0]. I have the condition sorted out using other logical or bitwise operators. I want to know why **xor** operator is not working in AngularJS.

I would like to ask - how AngularJS parses or evaluates passed expressions to directives (as ng-show is directive)

[As this question is put on hold,I cannot answer to this question myself.So I am editing the question with the answer in this section.This was an issue with angular documentation.They did not documented this unavailability of bitwise xor functionality.So I added this issue on their github page and this was committed.]

Comment: Since there's only one possibility when the form is shown, you can give that condition directly. `a && !b`

Comment: @juhana i need an explanation on xor application not & and |

Comment: `a && !b` fits your specs: `1 && !0 == 1`, `0 && !0 == 0`, and `1 && !1 == 0`. The confusion is why that's not good enough, and why you want xor specifically.

Comment: @juhana thanks for your answer.I will upvote your answer but cannot accept it.As i am not clear why xor is not working in angular js.Error is error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 30-30 [^] in expression [(businessFormAbout.$submitted)^(businessForm.$submitted)].Now you see what i am really looking for?I already have the condition sorted out using & and |

Comment: Angular parser doesn't have a xor operator because it's almost never used.

Comment: Do you care to provide me some links that proves your theory?

Comment: **Moderator note:** Keeps comments civil and constructive please

Comment: I am saying once more i have the condition sorted out using & and | operators.I want to know why xor operator is showing error in angular

Comment: @Debojyoti - https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/b5a0c8d2ea6d595fac18805e25c8a4797b07c7f1/src/ng/parse.js#L147 - if every if statements fails it will throw error `this.throwError('Unexpected next character ', this.index, this.index + 1);`

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski finally some help.I will check and see what is the reason for this kind of error

Comment: @KrzysztofSafjanowski This was an issue with angular documentation.They did not documented this unavailability of xor functionality.So added this issue on their github page and this was committed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simulate xor operation by `!=` instead (if both values are boolean, and in your case they are):

```
<form name="businessFormAbout" ng-show="businessFormAbout.$submitted != businessForm.$submitted">
```

Comment: Please read comments first.I have the condition sorted out.I want to know why xor operation is not working in angularjs

Comment: upvoting and accepting your answer as this was useful.But this was not the perfect answer as there was no perfect answer.Please see the edited question and see why