# Why doesn't AngularJS allow for xor operations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<form name="businessFormAbout" ng-show="(businessFormAbout.$submitted)^(businessForm.$submitted)">
```

This line shows error in console:

> [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at columns 30-30 [^] in expression [(businessFormAbout.$submitted)^(businessForm.$submitted)]

Comment: @deceze Go to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745107/how-to-use-xor-functionality-in-angular-js-expression

Comment: OK, now that we've got a clear question... Angular expressions use a custom parser. It's not straight Javascript, it's a mini language very very similar to Javascript but a subset of it at best. *Why* this doesn't contain the `^` operator is up to anyone's guess; try asking the original author(s).

Comment: @deceze if u all got a clear question now please delete the downvotes.because i don t think this is that bad a question to be getting so many downvotes

Comment: Also speaking of clear questions i also didnt get any clear answers until now.

Comment: No? Nothing whatsoever? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36763226/why-doesnt-angularjs-allow-for-xor-operations?noredirect=1#comment61105028_36763226

Comment: @deceze look i am not personally attacking you.Its just that i havent got any documentation in the net that says what you are saying.Your say feels right but you cant prove it

Comment: @deceze If i dont get "any" documentation on this matter how can i say it is 100 % solved? And the question got so many downvotes i fear i have to place some of my bounty (already scarce).

Comment: The closest documentation seems to be this: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression. However, there indeed doesn't appear to be any detailed description of the particular subset Angular expressions support.

Comment: @deceze now you cooled down and saw what i wanted you to see all this time

Comment: @deceze whatever man peace.I know just that it is a flaw of angular.A minor flaw but a flaw nevertheless.I just  seen you are among the top persons in this community.Really amused even you cannot give me a clear answer.This shows the angular guys have really not documented this well.Sorry for speaking to you rudely

Comment: The typical answer *why* something isn't implemented is *"because nobody has bothered to implement it."* Why that is is different for each particular case and ranges from *nobody thought of it* to *nobody had the time* to *it's difficult to implement*. If the official documentation doesn't state it, there's not a lot anyone else can tell you. That's pretty constant among all languages/libraries/projects/companies. Your best bet in that case is to contact the Angular development team, probably to open an issue on their Github page.

Comment: @deceze thank you for staying onto this.You are almost a legend SO guy(0.02% :O) so i will not argue with you :) .But atleast you will agree that "people refer to documentation to know about a programming language".And i think this is something which should have been in it.I thought bitwise xor works in js so it will work on angular but clearly it doesnt.

Comment: @deceze Its just that maybe angular guys doesnt respect xor operator.Poor guy :) ok will follow your advice and open an issue.But i didnt think this question which is an issue in angular itself will have so many downvotes.Seems the community is not all 'good' and all

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not AngularJS that doesn't support XOR: JavaScript itself doesn't support XOR as you might define it.

JS does have a bitwise XOR operator (^), but this only works for numbers.

You could create your own XOR function a bit like this:

```
function XOR(a,b) {
   return ( a || b ) && !( a && b );
}
```

Comment: angular js developers should have documented it that not even bitwise operator is included in angular library

Comment: Why? If you're developing in AngularJS, you ought to know JavaScript.

Comment: "not even bitwise operator is included in angular library".I knew xor works in javascript (bitwise)

Comment: xor operation not working is a minor flaw but a flaw nevertheless